# What should i start with after installing Ubuntu via Wubi?

Tags: system-installation

i am absolutely new to Ubuntu and i don't really know what to start with. 
Could you give me some ideas? 
What applications should i install first? 
I install it on a laptop with window 7 on it. 
I often use it for photo and video editing, coz i love taking photos, 
as well as audio editing (i am using adobe audition on win 7), 
and also making powerpoint slide(which i want to do the more coz sb said it's much easier to make slide via Linux), thz a lot.

Comment: If you edit your question to indicate what kind of things you use your computer to do, people might be able to give you more specific advice. Much of the software you'll need is already installed by default, like the LibreOffice office suite and the Firefox web browser.

Comment: you should first tell what do you want to do on your system ... are you just a general user (activities like surfing net watching videos listening music) or want something for a specific activity like development, or composing music or animation etc...

Comment: understood, editing the question, thz ;)

Comment: Install Gimp and Shotwell for photo and video editing respectively.Audacity is for audio editing.All these are available from the Software Center free of cost.

Answer (score 0):

First you need `Ubuntu restricted Extras` to play mp3 and videos.It also include flash to run videos on browser like Youtube videos.To install it,open `Ubuntu Software Center`,search and install `Ubuntu Restricted Extras`.Run Update Manager and do all the pending updates which has been released after the Ubuntu release.You can follow these links to have more tweak after Ubuntu Installation. http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html & http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/04/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html.

Comment: is that after the install the Ubuntu Restricted Extras, it would be able to play those media with sound as it doesn't have any sound rite now><

Comment: Ubuntu comes with completely free and open-source softwares,that means not included any proprietary softwares by default as flash and mp3 codecs.If you want these, you could install it by that way.

Comment: oic, let me try this out, thz

Comment: i have installed the Ubuntu Restricted Extras and also carried out 141 updates but i still can't hear a sound. >< What had happened??
And I do have installed flash. thz

Comment: Rather than replying for comments,it will be better to edit your post with what you followed.What I noticed that you did not mention about an audio problem anywhere in your post.But you asked about tweaks after installing Ubuntu.